# BIRT - Driver doesn't display in manage drivers

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, birt

I've just recently read a field guide book on BIRT- so I now understand how BIRT works. Now I've come to try and connect it to my a database rather than the sample one you get with it, however whenever I add my jar file in 'manage drivers' it doesn't display any new drivers under the drivers tab. I've tried every jar folder I've used in the past even as a test to see if it was just the first jar file I was trying to use was the problem.

Does anyone have any idea as to what could be wrong or what I may be doing wrong (I've followed the online tutorial from eclipse and it states that the driver should display when the jar file is added).

I've read lots of articles online and they all say that you need to place the file in the eclipse plugin directory and it states the path (I've used it) then to re-start eclipse and the driver should be available, mine is not upon restart.

Has anyone else ever faced this issue when setting up for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what type of database your are using but if it is SQL you probably need to install the correct driver.

Driver you probably want is; sgljdbc4.jar

There are many variables but if you are using set up similar to mine with Apache then you will need to copy the driver to these two folders.

C:\Program Files\eclipse-All-In_One4_3_2\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_4.3.1.v201308301349\drivers

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\Birt\WEB-INF\lib

Comment: Hi James the db I'm trying to connect to is DB2 type - does that answer your question into the type? Thank you very much for taking the time to answer! I already have what I believe to be the correct jar file in the first directory you mentioned, however I'm unsure as to if/where I'll find another directory I need to place this in (in reference to your second directory,would you have any idea?) :Thanks again :)

Comment: @user3373261 I am only familiar with SQL, so I can't offer assistance on others.  The second directory is only if you are using [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) to deliver your reports as HTTP (web)

Comment: Thank you for your help and taking the time to answer my question. Thanks for informing me about what the second directory was for :)